# French expression for a man gaining weight during pregnancy

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I was told some time ago that French have an expression for a man gaining weight while his wife/girlfriend is expecting a child (either out of solidarity or simply by being too stressed).  But I forgot the expression (and never knew how to spell it). Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are searching for (le syndrome de la) "couvade".

> Alors que leur partenaire est enceinte, certains pères éprouvent
> eux-mêmes des symptômes associés à la grossesse. Par exemple, ils ont
> des envies alimentaires particulières ou prennent du poids. Ces futurs
> papas éprouvent ce genre de symptômes d’empathie en réaction à la
> grossesse de leur partenaire. C’est ce qu’on appelle la « couvade ».

[Source](https://naitreetgrandir.com/fr/grossesse/trimestre1/grossesse-pere-symptomes-syndrome-couvade/#:%7E:text=Par%20exemple%2C%20ils%20ont%20des,r%C3%A9pandu%20que%20l%27on%20croit.)

[wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syndrome_de_la_couvade#:%7E:text=Le%20syndrome%20de%20la%20couvade,compagnon%20de%20la%20femme%20enceinte.)

It is also known as "grossesse nerveuse de l'homme". Couvade is constructed from the verb  [couver](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couvade) i.e. to sit on (the eggs) etc
(merci @Thélée_Lavoie for his feedback).